# Need for HTML-escaping when having regex checks in place?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a webapplication that takes user input via HTML-inputs and sends it to my tomcat server for further processing.

Currently my workflow looks like this:

**Client**

JS -> take HTML-input -> do regex check -> if successfull -> $.post(...)

**Server**

receive post data -> do regex check -> if successfull -> process data

From my understandig this should be fine and there is no need to do HTML-escaping

**BUT** I was wondering if there could still be a way to sneak in something that is not allowed.

---

**Further thinking:**

In my .java files the

`public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){...}`
methods do the following to receive the parameters that were sent:

```
String post_param_1 = request.getParameter("param_1");
```

This (obviously) has to happen before a regex check can be run on that particular parameter.

**Question #1:** could this maybe be an "open window" for attackers to sneak in/ cause unwanted behaviour within the java-code? The attacker could sent post-requests with a seperate tool, not through the regular website (for example)

**Question #2:** if Q#1 turns out to be true, could doing something like:

```
request.getParameter("param_1").matches(regex_string)
```

circumvent that?

**Question #3:** If my approach is sufficient, is it still desirable to do HTML-escaping at somepoint (probably between grabing the input in JS and before running it through the regex)?

Finally does anyone have any comments or suggestions on this topic, or am I missing something (like doing regex checks on client and server is too much)?

regards
Alkahna

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "HTML-escaping" you mean converting HTML special characters (like `<` and `>`) to their HTML entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`) then the answer is quite straightforward:

**You only need to escape user-provided input when you display that input back to the user.**

You store it in the database in plain-text format*.  This allows easier back-end text processing (like searching), as well as possibly exporting to other, non-HTML formats.

You escape the text only when inserting it in an HTML page.  Say for example you've retrieved the text from the database and stored it in a request attribute called "text", then in your JSP page you'd do either of these:

```
<c:out value="${text}" />
${fn:escapeXml(text)}
```

Where necessary to escape any special characters in it at this point.

If you're not storing the input in a database, but doing something else with it, the same principle applies:  You handle it in plain text and only escape it when inserting it into an HTML document.

---

Regarding your numbered questions:

**1** `"Could this maybe be an "open window" for attackers to sneak in/ cause unwanted behaviour within the java-code?"`

I'm not really sure what you're asking, here.  Obviously you need to get the parameter from the request's parameter map to do anything with it.  The user cannot inject **Java** code.

**2**  Doing `request.getParameter("param_1").matches(regex_string)` could result in a NullPointerException if `request.getParameter("param_1")` returns `null`.  You probably want to do something like this:

```
String post_param_1 = request.getParameter("param_1");
if (post_param_1 != null && post_param_1.matches(regex)) {
    // param present and valid
}
```

**3**  I think my main point above answers this.

---

*When I say "store it in plain text format" obviously you need to properly guard against SQL-injection when doing this

Comment: thx for your answer. For escaping in general: I only take input and process it on the server side. Display of text is handled with escaping already. For `1)` it was aiming at injection attacks in general (JS also). Thats the reason why I want to be on the safe side here. For `2)` you are right, thats what I'm doing already in my code at the moment. So concluding you could say that my approach is sufficient to prevent false input (regex) and through that automatically injection attacks as well?

Comment: Yes, escaping when displaying the text back to the user is all you need to prevent JS injection.